# Where is the SRC folder for .rdl files in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

This seems like this should be easy but I have not been able to find it.

I have rdl files that I need to add to report services. I don't want to go through the web interface and load reports one at a time. I would like to just drop my files into the source folder but I can't seem to find it. I am running R2 without IIS installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a source folder, to publish a report in SSRS you have to upload it, which in turn means it will be stored in a Sql Server database (by default called ReportServer, I think they end up in a table called Catalog, but last time I saw that was not officially documented by Microsoft).

The good news is that you don't necessarily have to upload the rdl files through the web interface one by one. You may publish them in one single go from the Report Designer or the Report Builder, or you may write your own deployment tool.

Comment: Also, for Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services I think SSRS is a much more common moniker than MSRS ;)

Comment: There is also a scripting tool for SSRS available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152874.aspx